# Iterate a function in ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am studying Angular. I am making an application: an user choose from one html selection, then fill two input fields. After this, the user press Update and the barcode script generates the code image with 3 parameters: the first select and the two input. ( these three are separated by some spaces ). So far, no problem.

I've added the button for add new forms, and the json array save the input correctly. I wanted to generate a barcode for each compiled form. How can i do? This is an easy example of what i am doing:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hxZb6g9tkwN0zpRmOMjw?p=preview

at the end of html you can find the script of barcode:

```
<div class="ean">
    <img id="barcodeImage" style="border: solid 1px black;"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateBarcode() 
    {
            var barcode = new bytescoutbarcode128();
            var space= "  ";
        var value = document.getElementById("barcodeValue").value;
        var value1 = document.getElementById("barcodeValue1").value;
        var value2 = document.getElementById("barcodeValue2").value;

        barcode.valueSet(value + space + value1 + space + value2);
        barcode.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        barcode.setBarWidth(2);

        var width = barcode.getMinWidth();

        barcode.setSize(width, 100);

        var barcodeImage = document.getElementById('barcodeImage');
        barcodeImage.src = barcode.exportToBase64(width, 100, 0);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitly not doing this the angular-way : mixing angular code and plein javascript, as you're doing, is generally not a good idea. It would be a good idea to [write an custom directive](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html) which bundle your barcode library.

Anyway, your `updateBarcode` function is getting its values directly from the html input fields (eg. `document.getElementById("barcodeValue").value`) and writing directly its results into the DOM. With angular you may not manipulate the DOM directly  but use your controller's scope (eg. `$scope.foods`).

To fix this, you can move your `updateBarcode` function into your angular controller and create an html container four your resulting images, achieving something like this :

```
app.controller('ProductController', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.foods = [ { ... } ]

  ...

  $scope.updateBarcode = function() {
    ...
    angular.forEach($scope.foods, function(food) {
      var value = food.selectproduct;
      var value1 = food.Quantity1;
      var value2 = food.Quantity2;
      ...
      // here, i'm not sure the following code will work as it is. If not, you'd better use a directive and angular.element()
      // but here is the general concept... 
      var barcodeContainer = document.getElementById('barcodeContainer');
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = barcode.exportToBase64(width, 100, 0);
      barcodeContainer.appendChild(img)
    }
  }
}
```

Then change your html accordingly :

```
 <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updateBarcode()" />
```

to:

```
 <input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="updateBarcode()" />
```

and

```
 <img id="barcodeImage" style="border: solid 1px black;"/>
```

to:

```
 <style type="text/css"> 
   #barcodeContainer img {
     border: solid 1px black;
   }
 </style>
 <div id="barcodeContainer">
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to iterate also the virtual keyboard showing when you press on the input field? http://plnkr.co/edit/4cP2xSDRgvHG29RuA92N?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Angular way! Don't mix plain Javascript with Angular. This will be misleading. BTW. You shouldn't use `id`s in a list. Id's should be unique. The function `document.getElementById` will always return the first element it finds with this `id`. This way you'll never find the other elements.

Create the barcode for each item in the list and angular will bind the generated barcode to the image.

```
  $scope.updateBarcode = function(food) {
    var barcode = new bytescoutbarcode128();

    barcode.valueSet([food.selectedproduct,food.Quantity1,food.Quantity2].join("  "));
    barcode.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
    barcode.setBarWidth(2);

    var width = barcode.getMinWidth();

    barcode.setSize(width, 100);

    food.barcodeSrc = barcode.exportToBase64(width, 100, 0);
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4scoibxyZ1EgJiRMex1V?p=preview

Comment: _I wanted to generate a barcode for each compiled form_...any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just click "update" button or what is the expected action of this button?

Comment: hmm nice one, just missed to click.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to iterate also the virtual keyboard showing when you press on the input field? http://plnkr.co/edit/4cP2xSDRgvHG29RuA92N?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this plukr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3DrWMSssx5UaQfHADoEr?p=preview) (forked from your sample), and use class instead of id:

```
<img class="xxx" code-index="{{$index}}">
```

Basically what you need is to put the image inside the repeater and find a way to address it.

But since you are learning angular, why not turn everything into a single component and use ng-click instead of onclick?